# GLM - compare the estimated model with the model with intercept-only

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, logit, intercept

I have this glm output.

[image]

How do the test to compare the estimated model with the model with intercept-only ? How can I comment on the result ?

Comment: Call `anova()` on the model object?